# No available Root space in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: mount, root

[image]Im facing an issue here. Cant able to add extra space to Ubuntu root (I have dual boot & using GRUB to switch OS).

Secondly, now cant directly access my ubuntu. From GRUB when i try to enter into ubuntu, after some authorization check, it freezes in a command line like UI.

I m using a bootable disc to check the disc usage of my existing ubuntu root. Attaching a screenshot here after. Please solve how to come out of this crap. Dont want to loose data .

****Edit*****

Now I have created some space from windows, that is being shown as unallocated space in the gparted summary. How to add this to my root volume, I m adding the screenshot of my gparted summary.
[image]

Comment: try to allocate enough disk-space for the system. A modern Ubuntu / Linux system needs at least 15- 20 GB, or better, depending on how you are using the system - that is what applications and data you have.

Comment: Thanks @SorenA, Yes thats what I really want to do badly. But cant figure out how to add these extra unallocated space to my root volume? any procedure?

Answer (score 0):

If you are booted into rescue mode and have a shell launched in your root volume, there are a couple things you can try to reclaim enough space to at least boot.

## Try cleaning old dependencies with apt

You can try running `apt autoremove`. This will clean out any unneeded dependencies.

## Try removing unneeded packages

This may be especially useful if you are running Ubuntu with a desktop interface, because it may have come with a lot of packages you won't be using. For instance, the firefox browser or openoffice. This entirely depends on what you are running though. To list currently installed packages, use `dpkg --list`. This will be a long list, so if you suspect something is present that you want to remove try running `dpkg --list | grep package_name`. If something can be removed, then uninstall with `apt remove package_name`.

Some other thoughts: You might be able to remove/zip some log files. Also, check your home directory for anything that can be removed.

Comment: Bro, i have used this. but nothing worked. Finally I reinstalled ubuntu in the existing partition. Still I'm having a low disc alert. only 2GB left & im unable to use update operations. How to add memory to root size?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using LVM, you must manipulate standard partitions to make enough space, although this is tedious because you have too many partitions.

If you happen to be using LVM (Logical Volume Manager), it is much more convenient. LVM is suitable for handling multiple volumes. The premise of this is that you have established an LVM volume group before installing the system.I didn't see the standard partition classification on the GParted screenshots you posted, so I **guess** you already have an LVM volume group (**but I haven't used MacOS X**).

If you want to make Ubuntu practical, you need at least 22 GiB of space to store applications and the system itself (excluding home directories).

You may need to continue to divide the space from the Windows partition (at least make the root partition have 22GiB space).

It's the only way.

Use GParted on Ubuntu LiveCD to partition it.

https://gparted.org/help.php